# Transferring objects from stack to stack not copying properly

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to check to see if a string is a palindrome by adding it into a stack, then popping out of that into a new stack and then comparing them at the end. However, when popping out into the new one, only about half of the elements are actually transferring over to the new stack and I'm not sure why. Here is the code:

```
public void menu () {
    opt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word to see if it is a Palindrome: ");
    String temp = transform(opt);       

    Stack stack = new Stack ();
    Stack stack2 = new Stack();

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {           
        stack.push(temp.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println(stack);

    for (int j = 0; j <= stack.size(); j++) {
        Object a = stack.pop();
        stack2.push(a);
    }
    System.out.println(stack2);

}
```

The only thing I can think of is that my `transform` method eliminates any white space by using `stack.replaceAll()`, but when I print out the first stack, there are no extra characters or anything like `,,H,` etc.. it just prints out the characters and thats it. Any  suggestions as to why that may be so or if there is a better way to go about this?

Comment: Take a pen and pencil and check what `for (int j = 0; j <= stack.size(); j++) {` does. What is the value of `j` at each iteration? What is the value of `stack.size()` at each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each iteration, you are simultaneously increasing j and decreasing the stack size. They're going to meet halfway through. Replace the loop control with

```
while (stack.size() > 0)
```

Comment: ahhhh! that totally makes sense I didn't even think about that happening. Thanks!!

Comment: Or `while(!stack.isEmpty())` : )